# How do I fix the NoClassDefFoundError in java Apache POI project?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have been battling to fix the NoClassDefFoundError exception without success. Getting a bit frustrated now. I am creating an application to read excel files using Apache POI library. This is what I am doing:

1. Downloaded the binary distribution of the library and saved it on a desktop folder called Apache POI library
2. Extracted files from the zip folder
3. I created a new project on Netbeans and called it apachePOI
4. On the project navigation tab of Netbeans for my project, I went to right click libraries>Add jar/Folder.. and imported all .jar files from the downloaded library. Added a total of 11 .jar files
5. I went to USER environment variables, and chose to add a new environment variable called classpath. On the variable value, I added the path to each of the every 11.jar files in my library. One such path is `C:\Users\wks\Desktop\Apache POI Library\poi-bin-3.17-20170915\poi-3.17`. I separated the paths with a semicolon
6. Thereafter, I created a very simple TestClass class which is compiling fine but failing to run with an error NoClassDefFoundError.The code in my class does nothing other than declaring an XSSFWorkbook like `XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file)`.

I am not using maven and had chosen not to use. Cannot figure out what I am doing wrong, though I suspect I am getting it wrong adding my library to the classpath as in step (5) above

Comment: I had once the same problem with Apache POI, most likely some dependencies are missing. Please show more information from stack trace then we could figure out what exactly is missing.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject
 at TestClass.main(TestClass.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 ... 1 more
C:\Users\wks\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Dear Michael, thanks for quick response. Have posted above the error I am getting in netbeans

Comment: Make sure you include the Apache POI dependencies too!

Comment: @Gagravarr. If you may help, how do I quickly do that?

Comment: How are you running your application?

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel. I created a project on NetBeans and added the apache POI jar files to the project library. Then, I defined a simple class with just a single line of code creating an instance of XSSFWorkbook. Then I did click run. So, I am running it directly from netbeans

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of the time this error happens when some dependencies are missing. I can see that you are trying to use `XSSFWorkbook` but according to Apache's website this component requires additional dependency `poi-ooxml`. You should also add `xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

You can find a list of all required dependencies under this [link](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components).

In my opinion you should start using Maven even for a simple program. It's a very useful tool and necessary for big projects.

Comment: ...  and as added bonus you can generate project files for your IDE ( or just open pom.xmk in idea )

Comment: @Michael. Thanks for your answer. Let me try adding the dependencies you have suggested and shall revert back on whether it worked

Comment: Although XmlBeans 2.6.0 has a few bugs, for which we are just trying to provide a official maven artifact, please don't use 2.3.0 or as the link says: "Wherever possible though, we recommend that you use XMLBeans 2.6.0 with Apache POI ..."

Comment: @kiwiwings. Thanks. Your assistance is always very useful Sir:))). I am working on configuring all the dependencies for my artifact POM and should revert back if everything goes as expected

Comment: @Michael Dz. Thanks for your answer. It worked. I did as you suggested and kept wondering why I chose not to use Maven on the first place. Dependency Management is smooth with it. Also, chose to use xmlbeans version 2.6.0 as had been suggested by kiwiwings. Much appreciation to all who commented

Answer (score 0):

Download poi-ooxml JAR 4.1.2 with all dependencies, which doesn't throw any ClassNotFoundException
https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/4.1.2/source-code